# How to make this code not print negative values?

Tags: java, hex

The code is written to convert hexadecimal values to decimal but when I enter an invalid digit such as "S" it prints out a negative value.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s = "a1";

    String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    int val = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        int d = digits.indexOf(c);
        val = 16*val + d;
    }
```

System.out.println("Equivalent dec Number is "+ val);

Comment: because indexOf(c) return -1 if the character doesn't exists in your digits variable

Comment: @billalGHILAS how can i change it? please help

Comment: if (d==-1) {then proceed differently..}

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 choices, add a condition

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    int d = digits.indexOf(c);
    if (d == -1) {
        val = -1;
        break;
    }
    val = 16*val + d;
}

if (val == -1) {
    System.out.println("Invalid number");
} else {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Or use java built-in converter like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s = "a1";
    try {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(s, 16);
        System.out.println(val);
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number");
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an exception if your input is not an hexadecimal number, like this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    int d = digits.indexOf(c);
    if (d == -1) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Your input is not an hexadecimal number");
    }
    val = 16 * val + d;
}
```

**Edit:** better alternative, so the for loop doesn't iterate at all if your input is not hexadecimal. Just put this before your for loop, it will find if your input contains a character not in your `digits` string and throw the exception in that case:

```java
if (!s.matches("[" + digits + "]+")) {
    throw new NumberFormatException("Your input is not an hexadecimal number");
}
```